# Is it necessary to check for system permissions on devices running Android Lollipop or lower?

Tags: java, android

If I want to check whether for example the permission to Modify System Settings is granted or not, is there any case where it's necessary below API 23? I have this code that checks whether the permission is granted on older Android versions and I was wondering if there's any scenario where it's needed:

```
public void checkWritePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        try {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS}, 4);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFound) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cant_find_system_settings, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            closeApp();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a permission check for the lower versions.

Comment: I don't have an Android Lollipop device but can't a user manually revoke app permissions?

Comment: not in lower versions, so you don't need to worry about that

Comment: But what if the user is rooted? Can he revoke permissions then?

Comment: I don't think it's possible even in the rooted device as the feature was introduced in later  android versions